# Add row to Entity Framework with hidden foreign key table and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have database tables like this:

**TABLE: User**
UserId
UserName

**TABLE: UserToOrganization**
UserId
OrganizationId

**TABLE: Organization**
OrganizationId
Organization

I'm using Entity Framework and since the `UserToOrganization` table is just made up of foreign keys Entity Framework hides this table.  I would like to associate a `User` to an `Organization` by adding an `User.UserId` and an `Organization.OrganizationId` to the `UserToOrganization` table.  However, since the `UserToOrganization` table is hidden, how do I add a row to this table in the database using Linq?

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: `since the UserToOrganization table is just made up of foreign keys Entity Framework hides this table.` - I've never had this happen to me. Does that table have a primary key as well, or just the two columns for foreign keys?

Comment: Just foreign keys.  I think you can turn off this feature but yes, these tables are hidden by default.  I can query these tables just fine but I'm not sure how to write to the hidden table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.  Seems obvious now that I think about it.

Here are my EF Tables as they are laid out in the edmx file (I probably should have provided this in my original question).  Notice that `User` has an `Organizations` and `Organization` has an `Users`.

**TABLE: User**
UserId
UserName
*Navigation Properties*
Organizations

**TABLE: Organization**
OrganizationId
Organization
*Navigation Properties*
Users

Here is how an insert is done on the hidden "UserToOrganization" FK table:

Step 1: Make sure that your foreign key table's columns are both primary keys.
Setp 2: Insert.

```
public void AddUserToOrganization(Guid UserId, int OrganizationId)
{
    // Get the user and the organization that you want to join
    var user = _data.Users.First(x => x.UserId == UserId);
    var org = _data.Organizations.First(x => x.OrganizationID == OrganizationId);
    // Add the organization to the user
    user.Organizations.Add(org);
    // Save
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add a primary key to the relationship table. That will make it visible and allow you to add entities normally.

```
TABLE: UserToOrganization
UserToOrganizationId primary key int identity(1,1), <--- Add this
UserId
OrganizationId
```

Don't forget to update your .edmx model by right clicking in the designer view -> `Update Model from Database.`

Comment: I thought about this and I'm sure it would have worked but I was thinking that there has to be a better, simple solution.  I didn't think that EF would hide the FK Table if it didn't have a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider writing a stored procedure and exposing it through your `ObjectContext`. You should be able to map the procedure's input to a `ComplexType` that represents the `UserToOrganization`. You could then do something like:

```
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    context.AddUserToOrganization(...);
}
```